# Unable to set the Stepper CSS through JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, js, lightning-progressstep

I have template folder where in I have a progress Stepper when I click on it, I want the step to be updated or some colour to be added in that.

```
<div>
    <ul id="progress-bar" class="progressbar">
      <template if:true={isClickable}>
        <template for:each={navobj} for:item="step" for:index="index">
          <li key={step.indivId}>
            <a
              key={step.indivId}
              data-target-id="progress-bar"
              data-appindvid={step.indivId}
              onclick={linkOnSelect}
              data-id={step.id}
              data-appid={step.appId}
              >{step.name}</a
            >
          </li>
        </template>
      </template>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

```
linkOnSelect(event)
    { 
        var  currStep=event.target.dataset.id;
        this.updateProgressStepperStateLink(currStep);    
    }
updateProgressStepperStateLink(dataidvar) {        
        console.log('data-id='+dataidvar);
        var Celm = test; 
        var tr=document.getElementById(dataidvar).style.color = "green"; 
        console.log('h@='+tr);  
       // var classItem = document.getElementsByClassName(".active");
        }
```

But the issue is, it is not getting set.

```
.progressbar li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: var(--peak-x-large);
    line-height: 24px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular;
    color: var(--river-bed);
    text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li.current {
    font-family: SourceSansPro-SemiBold;
    color: var(--shark);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.progressbar li:before {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid #B0BAC5;
    background-color: #B0BAC5;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.progressbar li:after {
    width: 75%;
    height: 4px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #B0BAC5;
    top: 7px;
    left: -37.5%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
    border-color: #00778F;
    background-color: #00778F;
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.progressbar li.current:before {
    border-color: #00778F;
    border-width: 4px;
    background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li.active:after, .progressbar li.current:after {
    background-color: #00778F;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to refer to the documentation: [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work)

> Don’t use the window or document global properties to query for DOM
> elements. See DOM Access Containment. Also, we don’t recommend using
> JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. It's better to use the Lightning Web
> Components HTML directives to write declarative code.

in a nutshell, you want to avoid using:

- document.getElementById
- document.getElementsByClassName

...etc, etc

Comment: Thanks glls But I tried this : const steps = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'); let step;
            let currentStepFlag = false;
            for (step of steps) {
                if (step.dataset.id === this.currentStepId) {
                    //currentStepFlag = true;
                    step.classList.add('current');
                } }step.classList.add('current'); And additionally I updated the li tag with data-id-><li key={step.indivId} data-id{step.id}>